# Count of squarefree numbers in range

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, discrete-mathematics

Given two numbers `x` and `y` , find count of numbers that are squarefree  where squarefree  number is one divisible by no perfect square, except `1`. For example, `10` is square-free but `18` is not, as it is divisible by `9 = 32`. Few positive square-free numbers are :

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15 ...
```

limits

```
1 <= X,Y <= 10^9

0 <= |X-Y| <= 10^6

x=10 , Y=15
```

gives

```
ans=5
```

My approach is to generate all prime till `squareroot(10^9)` (sieve of eratosthenes), and check whether each number in given range divisible by square of prime . Count of such numbers is substracted from length of range to give square free numbers .

But this approach time out in complexity , please suggest some other approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a list of square-free numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313267/getting-a-list-of-square-free-numbers)

Comment: But approach given in answer is same as mine , which times out complexity = O(primes*lenght_of_range)

Comment: Sieve the range instead of using trial division.

Comment: Google for "Mobius function" The fraction of not-squarefree numbers is `1 - (2/e)`, IIRC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

Let `f(n) = number of non-square-free numbers in 1 ... n`. We will only do inclusion-exclusion on the squares of primes, so as to avoid overcounting for squares of squares.

We have:

```
f(n) = n / 4      => these are divisible by 4, so NOT square-free
       +
       n / 9      => these are divisible by 9, so NOT square-free
       + 
       n / 25     => these are divisible by 16, so NOT square-free
       +
       ...
       -
       n / (4*9)  => these are divisible by both 4 and 9, so we overcounted
       -
       n / (4*25) => these are divisible by both 4 and 25, so we overcounted 
       -
       ...
```

How efficient is this?

We only need primes `p` such that `p^2 <= 10^9`, meaning `p < 31623`. This already isn't a lot of primes, any trivial sieve (or maybe even trial division) should be fast enough. Then apply inclusion-exclusion, which will also be fast since the products of squared primes will get large fast so you'll be able to terminate prematurely in a a lot of cases (`n / something = 0` whenever `something > n`).

In order to see why you'll be able to terminate prematurely, rewrite the above as:

```
f(n) = n / (2^2) -
       n / (2^2*3^2) +
       n / (2^2*3^2*5^2) -  <= this becomes 0 very fast. 
                               When it does, 
                               backtrack and increment the previous term.
                               For example, if this were 0,
                               you'd do - n / (2^2*5^2) next
       ...
```

More info on this [here](http://www.challenge.nm.org/archive/09-10/ProjectEuler.net_193_Solution+Explanation.pdf).

Comment: Intuitively this should run fast, but the inclusion-exclusion is a bit scary because (n choose k) grows exponentially in k. However in order for k to be large and still have the product of k distinct numbers be less than 30k, the range of numbers n has to be small. David Eisenstat gave running time bounds that look quite good. You should assume there are M/log(M) primes less than or equal to M and derive some upper bounds on your inclusion-exclusion complexity and see how it compares to O((Y-X) + sqrt(Y)) given by Eisenstat for solving the problem between endpoints X and Y.

Comment: I think this generalized approach is much more useful without the restriction |X-Y| < 10^6. With it this problem basically screams sieve

Comment: @user2566092 - `2^2*3^2*5^2*7^2*11^2*13^2*17^2` is already larger than `10^9`. I would expect this to be around `O(sqrt(Y))` since the product of squares of consecutive primes grows so fast. I don't know how to get a better bound right now. It should be very quick to implement and test if it fits whatever needs.

Comment: Another way to think about this algorithm is that we're sieving the primes and squarefree numbers from 2 to floor(sqrt(Y)), together with the parity of the number of prime divisors (we need four states: possible prime, possible squarefree with odd number of prime divisors, possible squarefree with even number of prime divisors, not squarefree). Then it's obvious that the running time is soft-O(sqrt(Y)).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment: assume that X <= Y and initialize a boolean array SF[X..Y] to be all true. For every k from 2 to floor(sqrt(Y)) (optionally including the composites; the asymptotic running time stays the same), for every multiple m of k² between X and Y, set SF[m] to false. Return the number of true values remaining in SF.

The running time is O((Y - X) + sqrt(Y)), since Σ<sub>k=1,...,∞</sub> 1/k² = π²/6.

Comment: although your solution seems right , but i am C programmer bool array implementation may be hard for me , i will try for java

Comment: @user3529205 Include `<stdbool.h>` or just (ab)use chars.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat This is basically the same solution that the OP has, except  OP was checking every number in the range for divisibility instead of just setting false directly for the numbers in the range that are multiples of the square. Good observation about the sum of inverse squares being bounded in the running time, giving good asymptotics. I have a feeling that when (Y - X) = O(sqrt(Y)) your solution is better than the accepted answer. Hence +1.

Comment: @user2566092 Perhaps, perhaps not. It depends on how bad the log factors are in practice.