# Find number of special numbers in a given range

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I am not able to reduce the complexity of this problem. Please give some better approach.

Is there a mathematical formula that i am not aware of or it can be done with better approach?

[Problem Link](http://www.hackerearth.com/adobe-hiring-challenge/algorithm/game-of-numbers-7/)

**Description:**

```
 A special number is not divisible by any number of the form Z*Z where (Z>1).
```

**Problem**: Find the number of special numbers in a given range.

`Integer Limit:10^9`

I have done it like this:

```
    import math
    def special(x):
        flag=1
        i=2
        if(x==0 or x==1 or x==2):
            return 1
        while(i*i <= x):               //This is the best i can think to limit the numbers.
            if(x%(i*i)==0):
                flag=0
                break
            i=i+1
        return flag

    t=int(raw_input())
    while(t):
        x,y=map(int,raw_input().split())
        count=0
        for i in xrange(x,y+1):
            if(special(i)):
                count+=1
        print(count)
        t=t-1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count of squarefree numbers in range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044332/count-of-squarefree-numbers-in-range)

Comment: Yes..its duplicate . Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `special(x)` you only have to iterate over primes less than or equal to sqrt(x).
So I would precompute a list of primes ([Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188)).

Comment: Why only primes? Suppose number is 36 then its divisible by 6*6. So in the special function we need to check for 6 which is not prime.